# Cannot connect to the MySQL from the Docker container on the AWS EC2

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I try to run my app with DB on single AWS EC2 (Ubuntu), and decided to try with docker.

I have very basic setup:

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  db:
    image: library/mysql:8.0.20
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    ports:
      # <Port exposed> : < MySQL Port running inside container>
      - '3306:3306'
    expose:
      # Opens port 3306 on the container
      - '3306'
      # Where our data will be persisted
    volumes:
      - my-db:/var/lib/mysql
# Names our volume
volumes:
  my-db:
```

And with following `.env` content:

```
MYSQL_DATABASE=db
MYSQL_USER=user
MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
MYSQL_HOST=localhost
```

I run it in detached mode with docker-compose:
`sudo docker-compose up -d`

And after when I try to connect from the host it fails, but what the more interesting, I'm not even able to connect from the container using following command:
`sudo docker exec -it db_1 mysql db -P 3306 --protocol=tcp -u root -h localhost -p`
I got the next response:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

There is nothing appearing in docker logs, and I'm out of ideas what possibly can be wrong.

Please help me if you have faced with this issue before or know what I'm missing!

Comment: try to use: `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` (including `.env` file) and restart container

Comment: You configured "user" in your .env and try to connect with "root". Is this just a result of replacing the real data here, or does the user really differ?

Comment: @num8er just tried, the same result

Comment: @Christian from what I understand mysql image would create a `root` user with MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD. I tried to connect both as `user` and as `root`, the same result

Comment: @num8er that's definitely not an issue cause I have no mysql installed on host machine, also double checked and it's not there

Comment: Can You try to do this way? http://joxi.ru/Rmzvv1uYl7ebmO  (as in screenshot) instead of reading .env file

Comment: You're right, that should work. Did you by chance use the volume before with different passwords? The passwords are stored in the database and with that in the volume. So changing the passwords in the .env would not change it in the volume.

Comment: @Christian I didn't, also I've pruned docker volumes few times, still no success :(

Comment: @num8er just tried as you suggested, restarted docker-compose, and still getting the same result

Comment: try to add this under `image:` line: `command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password`  cause new mysql does not use native password plugin by default

Comment: @num8er if you have time, I would really appreciate your help, here is a link https://us04web.zoom.us/j/72733661949?pwd=WFpQbnlHYXpDdUNaVGoyTWgzZ3F3dz09

Comment: @num8er that's I did, found somewhere on the Internet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Investigated issue with @nub8er, we found out that it was wrongly initially configured MySQL image. It looks like on the first run I've killed container before it has properly initialised, and for all next tried I was not able to connect properly.

Now everything works correctly, thank you @num8er for the help on investigation!